# Why is My Updated App Crashing on Launch for IOS8 Only?

Tags: ios, crash, ios8, cllocationmanager

I recently (October 2nd, 2014) submitted a new version of our app for IOS8. Previously it launched and ran on IOS8, but had some bugs, which I fixed before resubmission:

- Upgraded Stripe's Pod, because I was using an older version which began to experience an SSL error with IOS8.
- Updated my CLLocationManager code to use kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse (because IOS8 isn't backwards compatible for requesting the kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized status).
- Added a new, non-critical Swift view controller, to test using Swift in the same project/interoperability.

The app was granted expedited review, but when the new version finally appeared in the app store I was in for a nasty surprise.

**The app crashes on launch when on IOS8 devices. Whether an upgrade, or fresh install (delete app + data & re-download), but it doesn't do this on IO7.**

I've reached out to Apple for help resolving this, because the binary I sent them worked fine on my IO8 device, and my other IOS8 testers through Testflight—as well as on IOS7. The submitted binary should launch fine, but it won't.

Some research:

- [This post citing a similar problem](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:bHwDA1_8AAsJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/26172091/newly-submitted-app-to-app-store-crashes-on-launch-ios-8-only+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk) was created today at 1:34am GTM, before being deleted. Thanks Google Cache.
- [Back in June of 2012 Marco Arment discovered that Apple was messing with his submitted binaries](http://www.cnet.com/news/apps-crashing-apples-app-store-to-blame-says-developer/), causing them to "crash immediately". Not super useful, but it's interesting that this is potentially a problem.

Does anyone know what else could be causing this, or even how to go about debugging the issue? I'm perplexed because of how it runs perfectly over Testflight, etc.

Comment: I just pulled my app (approved and marked as ready for sale last night) from sale because it also crashes on launch. No idea where to start debugging it.

Comment: Do you guys have any stack traces? That should be the first place to look. You can symbolicate them against the submitted binary and track down where it's crashing.

Comment: My app crashes in the store before it even has a chance to report anything back to Apple, so I don't have anything to symbolicate against.

Comment: I think this might be a code signing identity problem. It reminds me of the kinds of crashes I saw when trying to add testflight users who were provisioned, but code signing was wrong...I did change that recently though. But this means Apple didn't even bother to test the distribution binary, which I thought was part of the review process.

Comment: Submitted a new binary, hopefully this one just works? Now I wait, and my users complain.

Comment: @DustinHoffman If you think so, you should [call Developer Relations](https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.php) (800-633-2152 in the US) and open a ticket.

Comment: I'm now experiencing a similar problem, although in my case it's affecting a TestFlight build. My app is working fine when I load it onto my test device via XCode, but when distributed through TestFlight onto the SAME device, it crashes. No crash log gets generated, either. Any ideas?

Comment: Here's an Apple developer thread discussing the issue: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/248897?start=0

Comment: Thanks you so much @JoeyC, great lead. Augh this is a terrible start to the weekend.

Comment: I'm the author of discussion on devforums. Thank you Dustin Hoffman for starting the issue here to be more public. My app is ready for sale with new certificates but still not available in the store (expedited review passed). Apple shame on you!

Comment: I hope it's not the certs, I didn't update those and resubmitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in the code signing process on the App Store, and has been fixed. The affected apps have had their code signatures fixed and are being pushed out as updates.